# Javascript basic search engine recipes

Tags: javascript, beginner, array, search

I have made a search engine for recipes. Requirements for this JS Project are as follow:

1. Create a function called `searchRecipes` that takes all recipes and an object with search criteria. This should return an array of recipes that match the search parameters
2. Create a function called `printRecipes` that takes an array of recipes.  The printlist are comment in the first lines . Code runs
3. If the search object has 2 or more of the 3 possible properties the found recipes should match each of the properties
4. The object can also have a `searchTerms` property. The value of the `searchTerms` property should always be a single string. For a recipe to match all of the given words (search terms) need to be present in either the name or the description of the recipe
5. A search with this search object should return all recipes that:

   - have “best” OR “cook” as the author
   - AND have “syrup” as an ingredient
   - AND have both “brunch” and “pancakes” in their name or description

Can anyone please review this code and point out what I can do better? While it works (after fixing). For instance it’s concerns JSON data. I do think I have to use `JSON.stringify()` method for converting the arrays to a string in order to make the search happen for comparing strings`

```js
const cakeRecipes = require("./Yazzrecipes.json");
    //// console.log(YazzRecipes[0]);

    // If you're ready to test: uncomment the code below.
    // printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, {})); // 162
    // printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, { ingredients: ["carrot"] })); // 3
    // printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, { authors: ["Good food"] })); // 32
    // printRecipes(searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, { searchTerms: "christmas simple" })); // 5
    // printRecipes(
    //     searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, {
    //         ingredients: ["nuts"],
    //         searchTerms: "christmas simple",
    //     })
    // ); // 2

    /* Parameters 
    const searchParams = {
      ingredients: ["carrot", "butter"],
    }; */

    // Creating a function that returns an array of recipes that match the search parameters
    const searchRecipes = (recipes, searchItem) => {  
      let ResultMatch = [].concat(recipes);
      if ("ingredients" in searchItem) {
        ResultMatch = ResultMatch.filter((recipe) => {
          const ingredientsInRecipe = recipe.Ingredients.toString();
          return searchItem.ingredients.every((ingredient) =>
            ingredientsInRecipe.includes(ingredient.toLowerCase())
          );
        });
      }
      if ("authors" in searchItem) {
        ResultMatch = ResultMatch.filter((recipe) => {
          return searchItem.authors.some((author) => {
            if (Object.is(recipe.Author, null)) {
              return false;
            } else {
              const recipeAuthor = recipe.Author.toLowerCase();
              return recipeAuthor.includes(author.toLowerCase());
            }
          });
        });
      }
      if ("searchTerms" in searchItem) {
        ResultMatch = ResultMatch.filter((recipe) => {
          const searchTerms = searchItem.searchTerms.split(" ");
          return searchTerms.every((searchTerm) => {
            if (Object.is(recipe.Description, null)) {
              const recipeName = recipe.Name.toLowerCase();
              return recipe.Name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
            } else {
              const recipeDescription = recipe.Description + " " + recipe.Name;
              return recipeDescription
                .toLowerCase()
                .includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase());
            }
          });
        });
      }
      return ResultMatch;
    };

    // Creating a function that takes an array of recipes
    const printRecipes = (foundRecipes) => {
      console.log(
        `Result of ${foundRecipes.length} that have been found as matches.\n\n______________________________________________\n`
      );

      // A listed display of the recipe, author(s), description and ingredients
      foundRecipes.forEach((recipe) => {
        console.log(`Recipe: ${recipe.Name}\n`);
        console.log(`Author(s): ${recipe.Author}\n`);
        console.log(`Description: \n${recipe.Description}\n`);
        console.log(`Ingredients:`);
        recipe.Ingredients.forEach((ingredient) => console.log("- " + ingredient));
        console.log("\n______________________________________________\n");
      });
    };



    // Printing parameters used for searching
    printRecipes(
      searchRecipes(cakeRecipes, {
        ingredients: ["syrup"],
        author: ["best", "cook"],
      searchTerms: "brunch pancakes",
      })
    );
```

[JSON file read](https://replit.com/@yazzynemri/Yazz-search-engine-JS-2408#Yazzrecipes.json)

Comment: Thanks I will use ' ' next time. I cant vote